# Energy of BEC in terms of temperature

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, bose-einstein-condensate

I have the formula for the energy of a Bosons gas 
$$ E(T) = \int_0^{\infty} d\epsilon \frac{4\pi}{2} \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3} (\frac{2m}{\hbar^2})^{3/2} \frac{\epsilon^{3/2}}{e^{-\beta\mu}e^{\beta\epsilon}-1} $$

I need to plot $\frac{E(T)}{NK_BT_F}$ vs $\frac{T}{T_F}$, so I'm trying to extract a $K_BT_C$ out of the constants by using the definition

$$ K_BT_C= \frac{2 \pi \hbar^2}{m g_{3/2}(1)} $$
where $T_C$ it's the critical temperature, and $g_{3/2}(1)$ it's a known number. 
$T_C$ is related to $T_F$ by their relation 
$$ \frac{T_C}{T_F} \approx 0.44 $$

But I can't manage to find the proper relation to get the expected function.

Comment: You talk about bosons but then need the Fermi temperature?

Comment: Indeed, I need to plot it in comparison to a fermi gas in the same scale $\frac{T}{T_F}$, I've already calculated the $\frac{\mu}{K_BT_F}$ and will calculate the integral numerically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you want, but your energy integral has an analytical result:
$$ E(T) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{d}\epsilon \frac{4\pi}{2} \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\left (\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2} \frac{\epsilon^{3/2}}{e^{-\beta\mu}e^{\beta\epsilon}-1} $$
$$\Rightarrow E(T, \mu) = \frac{3V}{4\sqrt{2}}\left ( \frac{m}{\hbar\pi} \right )^{3/2}g_{5/2}(\mathrm{e}^{\beta\mu})\frac{1}{\beta^{5/2}}, $$
where $\beta = k_{\mathrm{B}}T$.

If, as you say in the comments, you already have an expression for $\mu$, you can plug it in here so as to get $E(T)$. If this is for bosons at $T<T_{\mathrm{c}}$, $\mu = 0$ in ideal conditions.

Comment: Is $g_{5/2}(e^{\beta\mu})$ the Bose function? Let me do some algebra to see if I can get to $\frac{E(T)}{NK_BT_F}$

Comment: It's a Polylogarithmic function. Same as your $g_{3/2}$ but with a different exponent.